# MASM передача дробного значения в функцию

Tags: ассемблер, masm

Вопрос: как в функцию на *masm* передать параметром дробное (рациональное) значение типа *double* из кода на C/C++ на платформе x86 (регистры *XMMi* недоступны)? В Microsoft ABI информации не нашел. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Ну это же обычные байты в каком-то количестве.

Comment: Как я понял, у вас в проекте на С++ есть вставка кода на Асм? А точнее функция и ей нужно передать параметр double из С++? В самой функции на Асм есть этот параметр? Ведь она теоретически есть функция :) Функции в Асм берут необходимые данные для обработки, либо из стека, куда их положили перед вызовом! Либо из ячеек памяти, куда их положили для неё :)

Answer (score 0):

Double передаётся точно так же, как и все остальные значения - либо переменной, либо как параметр функции через стек.

Comment: Прошу прощения, вопрос некорректный, а куда попадает переданная переменная?

Comment: Переменная никуда не попадает, её содержимое доступно по адресу этой переменной. Переменная - это участок памяти для хранения данных. Для хранения double нужно 8 байтов. Для работы с переменной используется её имя, которое в конечном итоге преобразуется в адрес памяти, выделенный для хранения данных этой переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на заданный вопрос: переменная типа double передается из кодна на C++, как и остальные переменные, и попадает в итоге регистр(-ы) xmm(0-3).

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите